# Can I block an API Gateway resource for some API key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-api-gateway

I have an API Gateway with an API configured that requires an API Key. Now my question is, among all the get/post resources there are, can I make that for a specific API Key, this key won't be able to connect to some of them?

I know I could check it at the level code, but I would like to know if Amazon includes any option.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You don't want an API key to connect to another API key? Please edit your question to clarify the problem you're having, rather than just your proposed solution.

Comment: This looks like something that can be solved with an Authorizer on your API Gateway